# RainLab Plugin Builder issues with reordering

Tags: php, model, octobercms, nested-sortable

I'm trying to use the RainLab Plugin Builder and I'm having an issue when trying to reorder a series of inputted information.

At first, I was getting an error of...

**"The model must implement the NestedTree or Sortable Trait."**

So I looked at October CMS documentation for reordering and added use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Sortable; to the plugin model. Now I'm getting the error of...

**"Unknown column 'sort_order' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from jcbbuller_projects_ order by sort_order asc)"**

Is this because I didn't implement the sortable model trait until after I had inputted information into the fields? I have three test items pushed to this plugin's database so far, just to test out the reordering function.

Comment: please read this manual : https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#sortable , as from error you can see your table is missing `sort_order` column. you just need to add that column,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is missing `sort_order` column.

> Please read this manual : https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#sortable

from plugin builder just add `sort_order` column and default it to `0`. in migration file it should look like below code for `sort_order` column.

```
$table->integer('sort_order')->default(0);
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: This is right! I actually went into the database itself and plugged in a sort_order integer column with the default set to null. 

In the plugin, I did check the sort option—which I imagine would have automatically created the sort_order field, but it didn't... The migration file already had the sort_orcer column code in it, so I'm good there.